# Rails 3.2.8 and Heroku, throws application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm triying to deploy my rails 3.2.8 app to heroku and i'm getting this error all the time:

```
2012-11-22T13:26:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-11-22T13:26:30+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-11-22T13:26:30+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-11-22T13:26:30+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:24003
2012-11-22T13:26:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-11-22T13:26:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-11-22T13:26:49+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=facevid.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-11-22T13:26:49+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=facevid.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

it seems to be a assest error so i tried to precompile locally, change the application variable `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` , also change the environment variable `config.serve_static_assets = true`.

I have bundle install as production at my local environment and started production environment with webrick with no errors.

edit:

i will add my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Database gem 
# gem 'sqlite3'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

# heroku needs
gem 'pg', :group => :production
gem 'heroku', :group => :production
gem 'thin', :group => :production

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails" 
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Authentication gems
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'devise'
gem "koala"
```

I also created a supersimple example of rails 3.2.8 app to be pushed to heroku and i'm getting same error, the code of this application is here https://github.com/andresbravog/heroku-rails-3.2.8-test

Comment: Is there anything in the logs on Heroku?

Comment: Hit `heroku log` and see where webrick blew up. Heroku is less forgiving with asset compile than local setup

Comment: heroku log is not available if I run "heroku logs" i get what i'm showing. It will be nice to have more logs but i don't know how can i get it.

Comment: I think the command is "heroku run logs"

Comment: with `heroku run logs` i get `bash: logs: command not found`. I'm using heroku toolbelt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i will answer myself : I need to add config.ru file to my repo app in order to use thin.

hope it helps

Comment: i am facing the same problem what do you mean by repo app please explain a little